# Invisible UI in an QAction Signal Slot

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Good morning

I am programming a very simple for also very specific task using Qdesigner and C++ 17 under ubuntu.
The aims of my GUI and my issue are detail as follow.

AIMS:

I need to labelized a several dataset of images.
For Input an algorithm gave me three output that are stored in four folders, then I will diplay each image from the input dataset side to side with each one of the three corresponding output data and finaly take a boolean decision concerning the quality of the result of the algorithm.
Because I applied this algorithm on several dataset I want to select for each one the input and the three output folder when I start my project.

ISSUE:

I made the main window inside I load each image and took the decision.
I evaluate it in a constraint case it work well.
I order to achieve my goal for the opening project I made a second UI where I what the open projet use to looklike.
I evaluate that second UI in a context outside the main window it work well either.
So I call this ui in the slot method but there when I call the menu nothing happen.
Thanks to a `std::cout` instance I can check the slot method is called when I click on the menu or use the shortcut however nothing happen.

Here is the slot method that is called by the `QMenu` object.

```
void main_gui::on_New_Project_triggered()
{
    std::cout<<"NEW PROJECT "<<std::endl;

    new_project3 np(this,this);
    // new_project3 np(this,this->parent());

    np.show();
    np.raise();
    np.activateWindow();

}
```

The signature of the new_project3 class constructor is that :

```
new_project3(main_gui* main_window, QWidget *parent);
```

For the first argument I share the `main_gui` instance with the `new_project3` class in order to initialize the several `QStringList` without copy.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

SOLUTION:

The class `new_project3` inherited from the class `QWidget`.
For some reason I don't know I didn't arrive to make any instance of `new_project3` working inside the class inherited from `QMainWindows`.
However I modified the inheritance of `new_project3` in order to inherit from the class `QDialog` and then the following code work just fine :

```
void main_gui::on_New_Project_triggered()
{
    std::cout<<"NEW PROJECT "<<std::endl;

    new_project3 np(this,this);

    np.exec();

}
```

That have fix my issue.
I wonder to know what is written in `exec()` that fix my issue.
But that's will for another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.exec()` (member of `QDialog` but not of `QWidget`) execute an event loop and make it modal (synchronous, blocker). In your original code the widget was a local object, destroyed as far as the slot ended. As `.show()` is non-blocking, the widget was marked displayed and destroyed almost immediately.

Comment: That is the reason why I didn't see anything.
Thank you very much for the explanation.
Now it seem clear that any interaction with the user must inherit from QDialog.